# Sum of two random numbers

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, random, uniform-distribution

What is a character of distribution of the sum of two random numbers in the range $(0, 1)$? I guess that it should be uniform. But in case of specific example it's not.

Comment: are the random variables independent?

Comment: Assuming independence between $X,Y$, then if you think about it, it's clearly less probable that $X+Y = 1.999$ than that $X+Y = 1$. I know equalities don't really mean anything with continuous variables but here I talk about intuition. In the end the distribution of $X+Y$ will be triangular.

Comment: @Zubzub I understand what you are saying, but for a uniform, continuous distribution the probability of both cases equals 0.

Comment: @supinf Yes? it is.

Comment: Sure but let's assume we consider a small interval, say of size $0.01$. Then the probability that $X+Y$ lies in $1.99 \pm 0.01$ is lower than the probability that it lies around $1 \pm 0.01$.

Comment: See this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution)

Comment: @Zubzub Oh, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is the [Irwin–Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution). Thanks to @Zubzub.

Answer (score 0):

The probability distribution of a sum of independent random variables is the convolution of the probability distribution of those random variables.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions.

If you apply that principle, you will get an answer to your question.

Comment: Since the OP mentions a specific distribution, you might want to consider working out the suggested example.

Comment: @jvdhooft i think OP should try that first. If you want, you can think of my answer as merely giving a hint